# React native | add input fields on click

Tags: react-native, input, components

I'm a bit confused. I'm creating a workout app and I want to add another set when the plus sign is clicked and the input component is used to type in the weight and the reps in it.

the 3 dots on the right are menu to either edit the numbers, edit the comment, or delete the set. So each set that is added it would need 3 dot enu on the right to also show up.

I'm confused if this is Handling Touches, on click add, or something else. [image]